# Xcode 9.2 stucks on adding accounts after update of High Sierra

Tags: iphone-developer-program, xcode8.2, xcode9.2, macos-high-sierra

After updating to High Sierra, I am unable to add accounts to xcode. It stucks on add accounts and keeps on loading to infinity.I have two versions of xcode i;e, 8.3.3 and 9.2 and both are having same problem.